# Write a SQL query to return appropriate records with respect to DATE and Time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need a query to filter out records with date and time. It's an Oracle database and below is the table structure and few sample records:

Structure:

```
DATE_AND_TIME is Date and NOT NULL
DATE_AND_TIME is VARCHAR2 (8 char)
KEY is VARCHAR2 (256 Char)
```

Sample:

```
DATE_AND_TIME   DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT KEY
10-MAR-22       16:05:00                    500014
07-MAR-22       11:02:20                    500013
07-MAR-22       11:00:24                    500012
04-MAR-22       12:14:50                    500011
04-MAR-22       12:11:06                    500010
04-MAR-22       12:02:18                    500009
04-MAR-22       11:52:45                    500008
```

Sample query:

```
select DATE_AND_TIME,DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT,KEY
  from PRCI_AUDIT_DETAILS
 where  DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT > '12:02:18'
   and  DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT < '11:20:40'
   and  DATE_AND_TIME > '04-MAR-22'
   and  DATE_AND_TIME < '08-MAR-2022' 
 order  by DATE_AND_TIME DESC
```

I need query like if today is 12-MAR-2022 and 16:00:00. It should return records from 11-MAR-2022 16:50:58 to 12-MAR-2022 15:40:00.

Note: This is client table; can't change the structure.

Answer (score 2):

You should **never** store date/time vales as strings, use proper `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type. And you should **never** compare strings with `DATE` values.

In your example `11-DEC-2022` will come before `11-MAR-2000` because `D` comes before `M`. And `'08-MAR-2022'` comes before `'08-MAR-29'`

Data type of column `DATE_AND_TIME` is `DATE`. A `DATE` values always contains date and time part. Maybe in your case the time part is just `00:00:00`.

You say, you can't change the structure - talk to your client! A workaround could be to add a virtual column:

```
alter table PRCI_AUDIT_DETAILS ( REAL_DATE_AND_TIME DATE generated always as (
   TO_DATE(
      TO_CHAR(DATE_AND_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"') || DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT 
      DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 
      'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
) virtual )
```

Or you create a view:

```
create view v_PRCI_AUDIT_DETAILS as
select t.*, 
    TO_DATE(
          TO_CHAR(DATE_AND_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"') || DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT 
          DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 
          'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AS REAL_DATE_AND_TIME 
from PRCI_AUDIT_DETAILS t;
```

Then you can use it in your selection:

```
select DATE_AND_TIME,DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT,KEY
from PRCI_AUDIT_DETAILS
where REAL_DATE_AND_TIME > TO_DATE('04-MAR-22 12:02:18', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
   and REAL_DATE_AND_TIME < TO_DATE('08-MAR-2022 11:20:40', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
```

Note the different formats `RR` and `YYYY`, otherwise you may fall into the [Y2k-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)

Otherwise, if you cannot change the structure, you need to put the conversion into your query, e.g.

```
select DATE_AND_TIME,DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT,KEY
from PRCI_AUDIT_DETAILS
where TO_DATE(
      TO_CHAR(DATE_AND_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"') || DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT 
      DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 
      'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') > TO_DATE('04-MAR-22 12:02:18', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
   and TO_DATE(
      TO_CHAR(DATE_AND_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"') || DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT 
      DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 
      'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') < TO_DATE('08-MAR-2022 11:20:40', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
```

Or with a CTE expresssion:

```
WITH cte as (
    select t.*, 
       TO_DATE(
          TO_CHAR(DATE_AND_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"') || DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT 
          DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 
          'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AS REAL_DATE_AND_TIME 
    from PRCI_AUDIT_DETAILS t)
select DATE_AND_TIME,DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT,KEY
from cte
where REAL_DATE_AND_TIME > TO_DATE('04-MAR-22 12:02:18', 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
   and REAL_DATE_AND_TIME < TO_DATE('08-MAR-2022 11:20:40', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
```

For me it is not clear what you mean by "I need query like if today is 12-MAR-2022 and 16:00:00. It should return records from 11-MAR-2022 16:50:58 to 12-MAR-2022 15:40:00."?

Without further information I can just guess. Could be one of these:

- from `SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '50:58' MINUTE TO SECOND`
- from `SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '23:09:02' HOUR TO SECOND`
- to `SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '20' MINUTE`

Which let to:

```
select DATE_AND_TIME,DATE_AND_TIME_24HOUR_FORMAT,KEY
from PRCI_AUDIT_DETAILS
where REAL_DATE_AND_TIME > `SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '23:09:02' HOUR TO SECOND
   and REAL_DATE_AND_TIME < `SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '20' MINUTE
```